# ng serve not putting scripts in correct subfolder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a build setup that works fine using `ng build`, but I can't get the same to work with `ng serve`.

I have two Angular applications using the same `.angular-cli.json` but being deployed to two different folders. It looks something like this:

```
"apps": [
    {
        "name": "app1",
        "root": "Client",
        "outDir": "wwwroot/app1",
        "index": "index-app1.html",
        "main": "app1.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app1.json",
        "prefix": "app1"
    },
    {
        "name": "app2",
        "root": "Client",
        "outDir": "wwwroot/app2",
        "index": "index-app2.html",
        "main": "app2.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app2.json",
        "prefix": "app2",
    }
],
```

I can run `ng build --app=app1` or `ng build --app=app2` and they are built into `wwwroot/app1` and `wwwroot/app2`. I can then access the apps under `http://localhost:4000/app1` and `http://localhost:4000/app2`.

But in my development environment I'd like to be able to use `ng serve` (for live reloading). The problem is that `ng serve --app=app1` will create the js files directly under `wwwroot` (in a virtual directory), but `index-app1.html` look for them under `http://localhost/app1/main.bundle.js` for example.

I've tried to use different combination of `--base-ref` and `--output-path` but with no luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: From the CLI Wiki: *When running `ng serve`, the compiled output is served from memory, not from disk. This means that the application being served is not located on disk...*

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that it somehow could locate the files, in memory, under /app1

Comment: @R.Richards Seems that I have to run one app a time using `ng serve --base-href=/`

Comment: Curious, which app does it serve when you use `base-href`?

Comment: @R.Richards app1, unless i specify it explicitly using `--app=app2`

Comment: I would have never thought to try that since the wiki for `ng serve` doesn't show `--app` an option. But, just tried it... worked!

Comment: @R.Richards Yeah I know :D It was a pleasant surprise finding that it was possible to have multiple apps alongside each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to find a better solution than running one app at a time using `ng serve --base-href=/`.